# Can't boot into windows?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu on a second hard drive inside the computer by booting with the CD.

I now want to switch back to my main hard drive but I don't know how. When I unplug the Linux HD it goes into this black grub thingy and I don't know if my Windows got deleted because I didn't touch that HD. I don't have a Windows disk, my computer came with Windows 8. I need help please...

Answer (score 0):

type in the command line : sudo update-grub

This command will allow grub to search for other OSs installed in your system.

Comment: I did this after I installed ubuntu and GRUB did not show windows boot option, it was showing Ubuntu only. I did it and it worked for me. And BTW I do not think your windows files were deleted. It's just grub is not recognizing that there is another OS in there.

Comment: Omg tyvm I love you no homo lol

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232483/pc-wont-boot-anything-but-ubuntu/232601#232601) which is similer quetion.

### a) Option 1:

**Setps.....**

1) Insert the Windows 7 DVD into the CDROM. 
2) Shut down the computer. **(DO NOT RESTART)** 
3) Start the computer, & immediately after that start tapping on F12 which will give you boot options. Select CD/DVD ROM Over there.
4) Windows 7 should start the installation Process.

### b) Option 2:

**Steps......**

1) boot the system normally using Ubuntu installation that is there on Hard Drive.
2) Once you reach Ubuntu Desktop, insert Windows 7 DVD in DVD ROM Drive.
3) Ubuntu will automatically give you pop-up of the Windows 7 DVD & Start the Default auto-run program of Windows 7 DVD.
4) Click on the option to install Windows 7 from that pop-up menu.
**System may restart Automatically After step no. 4**
5) Windows 7 will start the installation.

Let me know if u have any further queries.

Comment: I don't have a disc it's windows 8

Comment: @Matt In your case you can download the windows 8 ISO and then burn it onto a DVD to use it. You can download the windows 8 from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/home). You can do all of that from Ubuntu as well.